# div resize without pushing content

Tags: html, css

I want to add 100px gap between the top of black box for both red and blue box.
At the same time I do not want to push both boxes (red and blue) to the bottom of the page. I tried using padding and margin for both boxes but it will push them downwards. How do I 'squeeze' the contents of both red and blue box without have to push them downwards? Is it okay to group both of them into 1 div then use CSS on that div? If so how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Could you post what you already have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try someting like :

```
.black-box{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

And for your red/blue divs :

```
.red, .blue {
   height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

But it depends on your current code. And it can works if you have absolute position for both colored divs, or display: inline-block.

Answer (score 2):

First you can use `Flexbox` on parent element and then you just need to set `box-sizing: border-box` and change `padding-top` on parent element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  margin: 5px;
}
.content:hover {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

You can also change `margin-top` on child elements

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}
.left,
.right {
  flex: 1;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
.left:hover,
.right:hover {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The key point is using `border-box` and set `padding-top` to the parent element.

#### HTML

```
<div class="black">
  <div class="red"></div><div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.black {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.red, .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would take a bit of "resizing" of your elements on hover. Take a look at this code snippet.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
}
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box1:hover,
.box2:hover {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Here is an alternative I consider which looks "cooler".

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent-div {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #b3ccff;
}
.box1,
.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid lightblue;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  background: #00cc66;
  margin: 5px;
}
.box1:hover,
.box2:hover {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```